# Jazz RTC Java API: How to find a Project Area by name

Tags: java, groovy, rational-team-concert

I am working an automation for IBM Rational Team Concert (IBM aka Jazz RTC).

The java/groovy script receives the project area name and needs to retrieve information about the project area, represented by an `IProjectArea` instance.

Which are the required API calls? Apparently, there is no such query available in the API.

Answer (score 1):

The API was not designed to search for project areas. Fortunately, there is the `IProcessClientService.findProcessArea(URI areaURI, Collection properties, IProgressMonitor monitor)` method:

1. Call `ITeamRepository.getClientLibrary(IProcessClientService)` to get a `IProcessClientService` instance.
2. Call `IProcessClientService.findProcessArea(URI areaURI, Collection properties, IProgressMonitor monitor)`.

   - `areaURI` is the project area name, 'encoded as URI' (can't explain why, it is internally converted back to string). I had to URL encode de name, but assuring that white-space is encoded as `%20` instead of `+` which would be the encoding standard.
   - I found no documentation for the `properties` collection. Works with null.
   - Progress monitor, may be null.
3. The method already returns a `IProcessArea` instance and not `IProcessAreaInstance` as I first expected by comparing with similar API methods. Therefore, no 'fetch' is needed.

```groovy
IProjectArea findProjectAreaByName(String name) {
  def processClient = repositoty.getClientLibrary(IProcessClientService) as IProcessClientService
  def uri = URI.create(URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8").replace('+','%20'))
  return processClient.findProcessArea(uri, null, null) as IProjectArea
}
```