# Jazz RTC Java API: How to list Components owned by a Project Area

Tags: java, groovy, rational-team-concert

I am working an automation for IBM Rational Team Concert (IBM aka Jazz RTC).

How may one a list all components owned by a specific project area?
Which are the required API calls?

I could not find any getters in the `IProjectArea` instance, nor service or client instances with such methods. And I could not figure out how to use `IComponentSearchCriteria` for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

The components owned by a project area may be queried using `IComponentSearchCriteria`. However, the API is not quite clear how to specify the owning project area.

1. Get the `IWorkspaceManager` from the `ITeamRepository`, which contains the `findComponents` method.
2. Get the `IProjectAreaHandle` for your project area. I you have only the project area name, [check this question to learn how to get the IProjectAreaHandle for the project area name.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67645977)
3. Create a `IComponentSearchCriteria` and set the `filterByOwnerOptional` to your `IProjectAreaHandle` instance.
4. Call `IWorkspaceManager.findComponents(...)` to get a list of `IComponentHandles`. The first parameter is the search criteria. Se second parameter is the maximum number of results (which I set to `IWorkspaceManager.MAX_QUERY_SIZE`, which is 512. The third parameter is the progress monitor, which may be `null`.
5. If you need to get component name, description or other attributes, then you need to call `IItemManager.fetchCompleteItems(...)` fetch the full `IComponent` instances.

Here is an example in Groovy:

```groovy
List<IComponentHandle> listComponents(String projectAreaName) {
    final manager = repositoty.getClientLibrary(IWorkspaceManager) as IWorkspaceManager;
    final criteria = IComponentSearchCriteria.FACTORY.newInstance();
    final IProjectArea projectArea = findProjectAreaByName(projectAreaName)
    criteria.filterByOwnerOptional.add(projectArea)
    final List<IComponentHandle> handles =  manager.findComponents(criteria, IWorkspaceManager.MAX_QUERY_SIZE, null)
    final itemManager = repositoty.itemManager()
    return itemManager.fetchCompleteItems(handles, IItemManager.DEFAULT, null) as List<IComponent>
}
```